# xslt cloning with partial data

Tags: xml, git, xslt, clone

I would like to clone a node with some of the data of the core-node. The values left and some other data should be put into another clone. This is the easiest described by an example.

Xml code example to manipulate:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <number>13245</number>
        <info>
            <desc>
                <value locale="en">some text in en</value>
                <value locale="es">some text in es</value>
            </desc>
            <calc>
                <value locale="en">some more text in en</value>
                <value locale="es">some more text in es</value>
            </calc>
            <date>2014-08-21</date>
        </info>
    </element>
</root>
```

Now what I am trying to achieve (and fail at all the time) is an output like:

```
<root>
    <element>
        <number>13245</number>
        <info>
            <desc>
                <value locale="es">some text in es</value>
            </desc>
            <calc>
                <value locale="es">some more text in es</value>
            </calc>
            <date>2014-08-21</date>
        </info>
    </element>
    <element>
        <number>13245</number>
        <info>
            <desc>
                <value locale="en">some text in en</value>
            </desc>
            <calc>
                <value locale="en">some more text in en</value>
            </calc>
            <date>2014-08-21</date>
        </info>
    </element>
</root>
```

The transformation should create two elements in the root with some core values like date and number but contain just the values of a single locale each.

I dont expect anyone to code this for me but a few pointers would go a long way. Thanks!

Comment: The problem with asking a question in the form of a (single) example is that we don't know what's given and what's just an example. Will there always be exactly two locales? Are they known in advance? Is the structure of your example - the names and the hierarchy of the nodes - constant? -- Also please indicate your version of XSLT: 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: Sorry you are absolutely right. My bad. Will try to put more information into the question next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way - not necessarily the best or the most efficient one - to arrive at the requested output:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform with tunneling parameter-->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:param name="locale"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="locale" select="$locale"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="element">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="locale" select="'es'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()">
            <xsl:with-param name="locale" select="'en'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value[@locale]">
    <xsl:param name="locale"/>
    <xsl:if test="@locale=$locale">
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks that works absolutely fine. Not that I doubted you. ;)
I will try to get the check for more instances than two locales done by myself. Dont want you to do all my work for me. :)

Comment: @user3146479 Well, the thing is, if there are more locales then the smart solution would loop over them. Especially if they are not known in advance and need to be extracted from the input. But that would be a topic for another question anyway.